# Config Vim plugin dbext to read password from a file

Tags: vim, dbext

I like Vim, enjoyed all the different plugins and dbext is one of them

However not happy with the fact that password is displayed as clear text on command line

Is there a way to configure dbext so it reads password from a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is and very easy to do

I tried following and it worked for me, this is one of my Mysql profile

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_live_export = 
'type=MYSQL:user=clear:passwd=`cat /Users/username/src/test/pw.txt`:dbname=abc
```

Just "cat" the file contains the password when you define the connection.

Now, I don't need to worry about others seeing my mysql user password from command line anymore.

Comment: After I clicked "Ask question" button, I noticed there are some text at bottom of the page, "Answer your own question - knowledge sharing Q&A style" and that is what I am doing. I thought this should help someone.